# creating an evenlistener for a list which was added using a node appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-applications, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a select list dynamically to my html. I've done this successfully by adding a node to the dom. My problem is on a separate javascript file I want to create an eventlistner which recognises the the newly created select list.

The HTML code works fine but the javascript eventlistner is not recognising changes being made to the list.

This is for a chrome extension popup screen

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Pop Up </TITLE>
    <script src="library.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT>
    function change(){
      var theDiv = document.getElementById("dropDownList");
      var select  = document.createElement('select');
      select.name = 'scrapbookID';
      select.id = 'scrapbookID';
      select.innerHTML = "<option value='15'>one</option>"+
                         "<option value='18'>two</option>"+
                         "<option value='20'>three</option>"+
                         "<option value='21'>four</option>";
      theDiv.appendChild(select);
    }
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="signout"> Your are Currently signed in.<BR>
      <A id="signOutPHP" href="file:///C:/Users/Kevin/AppData/Local/Temp/non19B.htm#">Sign Out</A>
        <DIV id="dropDownList">
          <BUTTON onclick="change()">Add List</BUTTON>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
  document.getElementById("scrapbookID").addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(" ...HElLoooooooosdvsdpovsdvni");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the event handler to the parent `<div />` and check `event.target` for the added element

```
document.getElementById("dropDownList").addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    if (ev.target.id === "scrapbookID") {
        console.log(" ...HElLoooooooosdvsdpovsdvni");
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then a solution could be;

To watch for changes to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) you can use [mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) (deprecated) or the new [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver)

Here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/6GbHF/) that demonstrates how these are used.

Both methods are not being used at the same time, the script checks to see if the new method, MutationObserver, is supported and then uses that, else it falls back to the deprecated mutation event.

What this script does is watches for changes to the `ul` with the id of `watch`. When it sees a change then it logs the information to the console using [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/console.log)

Using these priciples, you should be able to apply them to your situation, and watch for added elements and react to them accordingly.

HTML

```
<button id="button">Click me</button>
<ul id="watch"></span>
```

Javascript

```
/*jslint sub: true, maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true */
/* global global */

(function (global) {
    "use strict";

    if (typeof global.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        global.MutationObserver = global.WebKitMutationObserver || global.MozMutationObserver;
    }

    var watch = document.getElementById("watch");

    function whenClicked() {
        var li = document.createElement("li");

        li.textContent = "List element";
        watch.appendChild(li);
    }

    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", whenClicked, false);

    if (typeof global.MutationObserver !== "function") {
        watch.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (evt) {
            console.log("New element detected", evt.target);
        }, false);
    } else {
        var observer = new global.MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    console.log("New element detected", mutation.addedNodes[0]);
                }
            });
        });

        observer.observe(watch, {
            childList: true,
            characterData: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    }
}(window));
```

The whole thing is then wrapped in an anonymous [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) which is executed immediately, and into which we pass the [window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) which we then reference as the variable named `global`.

Finally, the first two lines are comments, but not any old comments, they are instructions that are used by [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/); a static code analysis tool used in javascript software development for checking if JavaScript source code complies with [coding conventions](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) set out by Douglas Crockford.

You can find further examples at;

html5rocks - [Detect DOM changes with Mutation Observers](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers)
hacks.mozilla.org - [DOM MutationObserver – reacting to DOM changes without killing browser performance.](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)

A G* search should bring you more results.

If I didn't understand your problem exactly, then at least I hope that this made for an interesting read.